# Does the 450D work with Winlink and allow Winlink to control changing frequencies and bands?

Tags: software, computer-control, ft-450d

Will the [450D](https://www.yaesu.com/indexVS.cfm?cmd=DisplayProducts&ProdCatID=102&encProdID=870B3CA7CFCB61E6A599B0EFEA2217E4&DivisionID=65&isArchived=0) computer control program interface with [Winlink](https://www.winlink.org) and allow Winlink to change radio frequencies/bands?

Comment: Hello Kenneth, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 1):

With correct settings for the transceiver's CAT interface in the Winlink software, Winlink should be able to control the transceiver. There should be no need for another "computer control program" interfacing with Winlink.